# Apply custom zscore function inplace to pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I want to apply my custom zscore function on rows of a pandas DataFrame df grouped by MonthNumber column:

```
def compure_z_score(df, columns):
    # apply the z-score method
    for column in columns:
        df[column] = (df[column] - df[column].mean()) / df[column].std(ddof=0)
        
    #return df

months = df['MonthNumber'].unique().tolist()
columns = ['T_AROME', 'T_ARPEGE']
for month in months:
    compure_z_score(df.query("MonthNumber == @month"), columns)
```

But I would like to apply compure_z_score() function to df inplace like C function with reference function call?

Thanks.

Comment: `df = df.groupby('MonthNumber')[columns].apply(scipy.stats.zscore)` replaces most of your code

Comment: Thanks but I got: TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: